# Classic ASP - Split date string on Character Count

Tags: date, vbscript, asp-classic, split

In Classic ASP, I have a date stored in the database as 'yyyymmdd' as a number.
I need to insert characters so I can use as date functions.
I understand to use Cdate, DateDiff etc, I need the change this to 'yyyy/mm/dd' ot 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DateSerial to get a Date from the parts (specified by position) of your input String:

```
>> s = "20140119"
>> d = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(s, 1, 4)), CInt(Mid(s, 5, 2)), Mid(s, 7, 2))
>> WScript.Echo d, TypeName(d)
>>
19.01.2014 Date  (<-- german locale)
```

As you know/have the parts, the easiest way to re-format your string is via Join:

```
>> t = Join(Array(Mid(s, 1, 4), Mid(s, 5, 2), Mid(s, 7, 2)), "-")
>> WScript.Echo t
>>
2014-01-19
```

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard, sorted